# Symfony API Platform Operations

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

Hi right now I trying out API Platfom and when I try to restrict the collectionOperations I get an error.

can tell me why I get this error?

```
Unknown named parameter $collectionOperations
```

Code

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;


use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/** 
 * A message
 * 
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
#[ApiResource(
    collectionOperations: [
        'get'
    ]
)]
```

Comment: Which version of API Platform do you use?

Comment: I use version "3.0"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`collectionOperations` is not available in ApiPlatform v3, but was part of v2. The code should now look like this:

```php
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\GetCollection;

#[ApiResource(operations: [
    new GetCollection()
])]
```

Have a look at [their documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#enabling-and-disabling-operations) for more details.